# how to jump to specific viewController after click "yes"in a alertView

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I want to jump to another viewController after i click a button in a AlertView.
anyone can give me a sample?

question update———————

i am trying this way:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

```
if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Logoff"]){


    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                   message:@“Logoff？"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* Confirm = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“Confirm" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

    {
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLoginView" sender:self];

        LoginViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    }];
    UIAlertAction* Cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:Confirm];

    [alert addAction:Cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

}

but i got this error:
Property 'performSegueWithIdentifier' not found on object of type 'GeneralSettingsTableViewController *’

did i miss anything?

Comment: Can you please let us know what you have tried and what issue you are facing?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: hi you got the solution?other wise i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alertView` depreciated use `UIAlertController` for example

```
 UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info"
                             message:@"You are using UIAlertController"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                    actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                    {
                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
                    // here add your segue for navigation for another view Controller
            // If you already created the segue use this
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yoursegueName" sender:self];

          // if you are used Storyboard ID use this

             LoginViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];



                    }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                       {
                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                       }];

[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: what if i want to jump to a ViewController named "LoginViewController",could you please show me the code below the "[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; "
 ,i just know the "prepare for segue"way,it's not working here.thanks in davance

Comment: thanks a lot ,but i got one error shows "the property'performSegueWithIdentifier' not found in the object of 'MyViewController'.MyViewController is the controller showing alertview.Do i have to declare it?

Comment: @H.JC -- one is connection through and another one is with out connection through , can you send your code to my mail ID karthik.saral@gmail.com, I will do the work

Comment: but i still got one confusion if i use your code the newViewController will be showed twice,i am wonderting why...

Answer (score 0):

Try this for pass control to specific viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self showAlert];
}  

-(void)showAlert{
   UIAlertView *alertForCall = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"time to choose" delegate:self   cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
     [alertForCall show];
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
          thirdViewController *thirdView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"third"];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdView animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use uialert view . It is deprecated